# Create a javascript filter on family tree to display or not people

Tags: javascript, filter, system

I didn't find such a specific topic so I hope there is anyone here who could help me. Here's the deal: I'm making a family tree, for my personal purpose, and I struggle with finding something viable to filter people on my tree. As a matter of fact, on top of my page, I want to use a filter with  and  with the different family names appearing in my tree. I want just by clicking on a name, all the people with this name only remain, and so on with the other names.

Here's my shortened HTML:

```
<div class="searchbar">
            <h3>Title</h3>
            <select>
                <option value="all">TOUS</option>
                <option value="name1">NAME 1</option>
                <option value="name2">NAME 2</option>
                <option value="name3">NAME 3</option>
                <option value="name4">NAME 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>

<div class="content">
            <h2>Gen 0</h2>

            <div class="person origin name1">
                <h3>1 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
                <p>BIRTH</p>
                <p>WEDDING</p>
                <p>DEATH</p>
            </div>

            <h2>Gen -1</h2>

            <div class="person name1">
                <h3>2 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
                <p>BIRTH</p>
                <p>WEDDING</p>
                <p>DEATH</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div class="person name2">
                <h3>3 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
                <p>BIRTH</p>
                <p>WEDDING</p>
                <p>DEATH</p>
            </div>
</div>
```

and so on. I tried many different kinds of javascript but none of them worked. Could anyone could help me?

Comment: What have you tried / Where are you stuck? In my approach I would have following steps: (0) save the data as array in JS; (1) create a function that takes the data as an argument and insert it into the html; (2) call this function for the initial display without filter; (3) add an event listener for the filter; (4) on a filter event, filter the list based on the filter, remove the old html and call the insert function

Comment: This whole question is far too broad as per guidelines outlined in the [help]. You are basically asking others to write the code for you. That is just not how this site works. You might want to look for a charting library that will do a lot of the visual display for you

Comment: I suspect that there are also tutorials around that could help you with a family tree

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```js
$('select.filtter').change(function(){
var filters = $.map($('select.filtter').toArray(), function(e){
    return $(e).val();
}).join(".");
$("div.content").find("div.person").hide();
$("div.content").find("div.person." + filters).show();
if($("div.person:visible").length === 0){
    $(".alert").show()
}else{
    $(".alert").hide()
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filtters=wrap">
  <label class="visually-hidden" for="data-title">Title</label>
    <select class="filtter" id="data-actor-lang">
        <option value="all">TOUS</option>
        <option value="name1">NAME 1</option>
        <option value="name2">NAME 2</option>
        <option value="name3">NAME 3</option>
        <option value="name4">NAME 4</option>
    </select>
</div>


<div class="content">
  <h2>Gen 0</h2>
  <div class="person origin all name1">
    <h3>1 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
    <p>BIRTH</p>
    <p>WEDDING</p>
    <p>DEATH</p>
  </div>
  <h2>Gen -1</h2>
  <div class="person all name1">
    <h3>2 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
    <p>BIRTH</p>
    <p>WEDDING</p>
    <p>DEATH</p>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="person all name2">
    <h3>3 ・ FULL NAME</h3>
    <p>BIRTH</p>
    <p>WEDDING</p>
    <p>DEATH</p>
  </div>
  <div class="alert" style="display:none;">Sorry, no person found.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add a bit of an explanation of why/how your code works?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).